# Why buttons given at right of android emulator do not work?

Tags: android

I have just installed on my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. When I launch emulator to run some app, buttons like menu, back, home given on right are disabled. Can someone help me how to enable them.

My emulator config:

```
device: nexus 7
target: android 2.2 api level 8
cpu: arm
keyboard: enable
skin : enable
ram: 1024
vm heap: 32
internal storage: 200
```

[image: avd details]

Comment: delete it , again create new emulator

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable the hardware main keys (note that it is set to `no` in your screenshot).

Edit the AVD, select `New` from the `Hardware` section and then find the `Hardware Back/Home keys`, click OK and ensure that the value for this property is set to `yes`.

If you are using a template for your device you should change the template under the `Device Definitions` tab instead. Here you should choose `Hardware` in the `Buttons` dropdown.